# LINEにOPENAIを繋げてBOTを作っていますが401エラーが何度も出てきて対処法がわからずに困っています。

Tags: google-apps-script, api, line

以下のコードをGoogleAppsScriptを用いてデプロイしたのですがwebhookが401エラーを出し続けていて対処法がわからず困っています。
以下は使用したソースコードになります。

```js
const LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'ご自身のLINEのアクセストークンを入力してください';
const OPENAI_APIKEY = 'ご自身のOpenAIのAPIキーを入力してください';

function doPost(e) {
  const event = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events[0];

  const replyToken = event.replyToken;
  let userMessage = event.message.text;
  const url = 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/reply';

  if (userMessage === undefined) {
    // メッセージ以外(スタンプや画像など)が送られてきた場合
    userMessage = '？？？';
  }

  const prompt = userMessage;
  const requestOptions = {
    "method": "post",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer "+ OPENAI_APIKEY
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify({
      "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      "messages": [ 
        {"role": "system", "content": `
答えた後に、
知らんけど。を追記してください
        `},
         {"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    })
  }
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", requestOptions);

  const responseText = response.getContentText();
  const json = JSON.parse(responseText);
  const text = json['choices'][0]['message']['content'].trim();

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    'headers': {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + LINE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    },
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify({
      'replyToken': replyToken,
      'messages': [{
        'type': 'text',
        'text': text,
      }]
    })
  });
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'content': 'post ok'})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

こちらを実行した際に表示されるエラーになります。

```
15:11:38    エラー 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'postData')
doPost  @ コード.gs:5
```

解決策がわからないのでよろしくわかる方よろしくおねがいします。

参考サイトはこちらになります
https://zenn.dev/robes/articles/c8dda8b42afab8

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/fy3lxlzv6xg55v) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)